# Using the this-method for values of radiobuttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, this

I have this fieldset in Jquery Mobile:

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
  <legend>Highest education:</legend>
    <label for="uni">University</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="uni" value="uni">
    <label for="coll">College</label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="coll" value="coll">
  </fieldset>
 </div>
```

And I want to store the value in a variable `education` and check whether at least one radiobutton is checked. Since I have more of such choices and use it several times, I thought about using `this` instead of assigning manually values to the variable. The code below does not work, however.

Can someone help me with this?

```
if($("#uni").is(":checked") || $("#coll").is(":checked")) {
edu = $(this).val();
    } else {
        return false
    }
```

Comment: Could you please create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Why are the options for the 'highest education' given the name 'gender'? And I'm assuming you want to check that one radio is checked in every group?

Comment: @DavidThomas Yes, I want to check it per group. The gender name is still in there form copy/pasting from another menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the clarification, in the comments to your question, that you want to check that a radio `<input>` has been checked in each of the groups, I'd suggest:

```
// selects all the relevant fieldsets (on the assumption they all
// share the same 'data-role' attribute and value:
var fieldsets = $('fieldset[data-role="controlgroup"]'),
// compares the number of fieldsets with the number of fieldsets that have...
    allChecked = fieldsets.length === fieldsets.filter(function(){
        // one, or more, checked radio inputs:
        return $(this).find('input[type="radio"]:checked').length;
    // and assesses whether the number of fieldsets is the same as the
    // number of fieldsets with at least one radio input checked
    }).length;
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [`:checked` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#checked).
- jQuery:

  - [attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]`) Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).